# Implementing UIButtons for selection in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I'm new to iOS development and I'm working on a Fire Safety App. I would like to give the user the option of 3 risk levels: Low, Medium and High by using (I suppose) 3 UIButtons which the user can tap, and which ever one they tap would turn a certain colour.

I've managed to get 3 UIButtons working, and they can change colour when tapped but if I tap another I can't get the previous button to change back and I've had difficulties getting a value for them (For example when submitted if the user pressed Low I would use the number 2 for calculations)

To show this I did a quick drawing:
[Button Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZJwZ.jpg)

Thanks for your help :)

==== EDIT ====

I am now using a Segmented Control instead of UIButtons to do this. But I need to know how to use them in an if statement

```
@IBOutlet var RiskChoice: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var ValueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var CalcButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func Calculate(sender: UIButton) {

if (RiskChoice.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
  ValueLabel.text = String("Low")
}
```

Nothing appears in the Label I have set up.. Could someone direct me here?

Comment: Please post code you already have

Comment: If you don't have any restriction you can use [segmented control](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html)... Otherwise give some code what you have tried

Comment: it will be better if you show what code you tried, Since there are many ways to do this!

Comment: Okay see my original post for the changes I've made, just need directing on a Segmented Control now :) @SuhasPatil

Answer (score 1):

You can just reset all the 3 buttons to their default state when any of the button is tapped and then highlight the current button.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

/** Reset all button to default state*/
resetAllButtons()

/** Highlight current button */
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
sender.titleColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}


private func resetAllButtons() {

button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
button1.titleColor = UIColor.blackColor() /// Or use this : button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor, forState: .Normal)

button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
button2.titleColor = UIColor.blackColor()

button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
button3.titleColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: This is the answer